# Reverse geocode not working in Subgurim GoogleMaps

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, subgurim-maps

I am using Subgurim GoogleMaps mapping library in my project. `Geocode` function sometimes does not work in server system but the same code works fine in localhost.

I am converting latitude and longitude to human readable address but sometimes `Geocode` status returns 500. The code is this:

```
string sMapKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googlemaps.subgurim.net"];
GeoCode objAddress = new GeoCode();
objAddress = GMap.geoCodeRequest(new GLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0]0]),Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][1])),sMapKey);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (objAddress.valid)
{
    sb.Append(objAddress.Placemark.address.ToString());
    string address = sb.ToString();
    lblPlace.Text = address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some changes in the API lately (that rendered old V2 API calls unusable) but installing the latest version (4.1.0.5 or 4.1.0.6 on NuGet) of the library should solve the problem.

If the problem occurs only with certain data please tell which are the inputs so it can be reproduced and diagnosed properly. The code seems ok.

Bear in mind that when using localhost, all the license checking mechanisms are disabled (I don't know exactly the limits but surely are not the same as when using an API key under a named domain). This means that maybe the problem is in the restrictions of the license.

Comment: Hi. Here we are using visual studio 2008.can i install nuget 4.1.0.5 on vs2008 and OS was window server 2003.

Comment: It does not matter, the version you can download on the page is the same.

Comment: yes i am downloaded the gmaps_v4_1_0_5 file..but it not work sometimes.

Comment: If you don't specify when in which cases it does not work is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: it was not work after 2:00 pm, after some times(4 to 6 hr) automatically it will works.